# How to get the coverage of behave testing?

Tags: python, bdd, coverage.py

I am using behave for BDD and am looking to get code coverage of behave. 
Here is my command I tried:

```
coverage run --source='/app/code' -m behave
```

The final output I am getting here is:

```
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
```

and code coverage is always 0% for each of my source file.

Comment: Do you see console output from behave?